# Cannot add graphstory:dev-plus to node.js app on heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

It seems like the heroku CLI is running into problems when I try
to set up a graphstory:dev-plus addon.

```
# heroku addons:create graphstory:dev-plus
Creating graphstory:dev-plus on ⬢ ananke-dev... !
 ▸    You may only have one instance of the Graph Story Heroku Add-on per Heroku application.
```

I do not understand the error message here, as I do not have any addons:

```
# heroku addons
No add-ons for app ananke-dev.
```

Can anyone clarify what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having this problem too :/

Answer (score 0):

Graphstory has officially discontinued its heroku add-on for the neo4j data store.